# Vue: Swappable dynamic component not render anything inside of itself

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a `v-for` and I used `<component :is="">` in it, when it's render `ValidationProvider`, everything is right but when it render `span` it doesn't render anything inside.

```html
<component
 :is="item.validation_rules ? 'ValidationProvider' : 'span'"
 v-slot="{ errors }"
 :name="item.label"
 :rules="item.validation_rules"
>
 Place for inputs...
</component>
```

output:

```html
<span name="Field name" rules=""></span>
```

Exepted output:

```html
<span name="Field name" rules="">
  Place for inputs...
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can only render a "component", hence `span` is a simple HTML tag. I don't have any official source confirming that tho.

Oh and you also have some flexibility with `vee-validate` and the `Validation Provider`, as seen here: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/api/validation-provider.html#rendering
You can pass a `tag="span"`, not sure if it can help you somehow.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that when I haven't `item.validation_rules`, ValidationObserver stop observe that input

Comment: You could maybe set the mode as `passive`, if you have some "typing" validation (wo/ a CTA for the validation): https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2518#issuecomment-560502213 What is the issue of it running in the background ? Also, you could try rendering a dumb component with a  `span` inside of it.